# Auth Session is always null

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I've used different methods without success to setup a simple Iframe app that previously works with the old 4.x Facebook C# SDK. I use a regular NET 4.0 web app, I don't use MVC. In my FB app configuration I've enabled all the new methods (like oAuth2) but disabled the options marked as deprecated.

The Authorizer Session is always null with a logged user fan of my page, too.

```
Authorizer auth = new Authorizer(FacebookContext.Current.AppId, FacebookContext.Current.AppSecret, new HttpContextWrapper(Context));
auth.Perms = "user_about_me,user_birthday,user_location";

if (auth.Session != null && auth.Session.AccessToken != null)
    fbApp = new FacebookClient(auth.Session.AccessToken);           

if(auth.IsAuthorized())
        //show the app
```

Probably I've missing something stupid, but I can't get it to works. I think is something related to the cookie, the difference in my SDK 4.x web.config is the cookieSupport="false" not supported in the facebookSettings...
Thanks in advance to the people who can help me :)
Joe

Answer (score 0):

In version 5 the cookie is used if it is present in the request, otherwise it will look for other request parameters such as signed_request. You should not be using a cookie with a canvas app as you will run into cross-domain issues with certain browsers.

Ensure you have POST for Canvas enabled.

Instead of using Authorizer try the CanvasAuthorizer class (5.0.3) or FacebookCanvasAuthorizer class (latest source).

Instantiate it like so:

```
var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Perms = "user_about_me,user_birthday,user_location" };
```

You don't need to pass the appId or appSecret into the constructor as it will be taken from your Web.config section.

Comment: POST for Canvas is enabled but it doesn't work, also with the CanvasAuthorizer as you suggest. Note: looking into the HttpContext I can see the signed_request parameter into Request.Form

Comment: If you load the symbols for the library and step into CanvasAuthorizer while debugging what do you see happening in FacebookWebUtils.GetSession?

Comment: Please note: to debug symbols I've downloaded the latest source code from the repository. I needed to refactor my code snippet to use the FacebookCanvasAuthorizer class. In FacebookSession.GetSession the signedRequest.AccessToken is null and sessionCookieValue is null, too. I notice that the FacebookSession class constructor is never fired so it can't parse the signed_request form parameter.